# Convert QTableView into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyside6

I have a GUI that I'm working on that loads its data from a Pandas Dataframe and displays it (functions as it should), you can than using QSortFilterProxyModel filter the data and search for the information you'd like.

The goal is to then take the current displayed data in the QTableView, whether you've filtered for specific values or not, and convert that back into a Pandas Dataframe so that it can be exported to an Excel document with ExcelWriter.

Here is an attempt however it does not populate any data into the save file that is later created

```
    p_data = []
    p_model = self.PortTable.model()
    
    for row in range(p_model.rowCount()):
        rowRes = []
        for column in range(p_model.columnCount()):
            index = p_model.index(row, column)
            item = p_model.data(index)
            if item != '':
                rowRes.append(item)
            p_data.append(rowRes)
        p_df = pd.DataFrame(p_data)
```

Comment: What is the question? If you're asking "how to do it", then it's not a very appropriate questions (remember that StackOverflow is not a tutorial). Did you actually try something? Fundamentally speaking, you should just create a new dataframe, then iterate through the rows/columns of the sorted model.

Comment: My code didn't paste initially, I added it in there now.

Comment: That code seems wrong: either you didn't paste it correctly, or the indentation of the last two lines is off by one level. In either case, please provide a valid [mre] (and check that the syntax/indentation is consistent with your code).

Comment: There are 2 "unclear" things that I see in your code: 1) You want to build dataframe from p_data. But what is p_data that you constructs? It looks like a mess of lists. 2) You mentioned that your model takes data from pandas dataframe. This means you use some custom model and data() method is redefined. So it isn't clear what actually comes into item variable.